# How to change order of flex-box programmatically in React JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs

The order of flex-box is not changing on click of Notification received,

I tried by getting element by class name and assigning the order for the same. but it is not working.

But changing innerHTML is working

```
document.getElementsByClassName(style.notificationCard)[0].innerHTML = "notification received";
```

```js
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import style from './HomePage.css'
import * as ReactDOM from "react-dom";

class HomePage extends Component {

    onNotificationClick=()=> {
        document.getElementsByClassName(style.notificationCard)[0].order = 2;
    };

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <div className={style.main}>
                    <div className={style.createCard}>
                        Create memory
                    </div>
                    <div className={style.notificationCard}>
                        Notification
                    </div>
                    <div className={style.alertsCard}>
                        alerts
                    </div>
                    <div className={style.groupsCard}>
                        groups
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <button onClick={this.onNotificationClick}>Notification received</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default HomePage;
```

```css
.main{
    background: #969696;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-evenly;
    align-items: center;
    flex-direction: column;

}

.createCard{
    order: 2;
    background: aqua;
    width: 100%;
    height: 120px;
}

.notificationCard{
    order: 1;
    width: 100%;
    height: 120px;
}

.alertsCard{
    order: 4;
    width: 100%;
    background: aqua;
    height: 120px;

}
.groupsCard{
    order: 3;
    width: 100%;
    height: 120px;
}
```

Comment: A more elegant way would be to create a state in your component ( for exemple notificationRecieved false by default ) then change it with your onClick event. After that you can add a class in your css .notificationCardRecieved and use class condition in the render `className={style.notificationCard + (this.state.notificationRecieved ? style.notificationCardRecieved : '')}`

Answer (score 1):

Don't use `getElementsByClassName`, or any other selector-based method to access parts of your component. Instead, use component state, or if you have no alternative, a `ref`. Here, component state will work fine, as shown below.

Note that I have made some other changes to make the code snippet work, such as using React from a CDN and "normal" CSS instead of importing `style`. I'm not suggesting that you change these things in your application.

```js
class HomePage extends React.Component {
    state = {
      notificationIsClicked: false
    }

    onNotificationClick=()=> {
        this.setState({ notificationIsClicked: true })
    };

    render() {
        const { notificationIsClicked } = this.state;
        return (
            <div>
                <div className={`main ${notificationIsClicked ? "clicked" : ""}`}>
                    <div className={"createCard"}>
                        Create memory
                    </div>
                    <div 
                        className={"notificationCard"}>
                        Notification
                    </div>
                    <div className={"alertsCard"}>
                        alerts
                    </div>
                    <div className={"groupsCard"}>
                        groups
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <button onClick={this.onNotificationClick}>Notification received</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

ReactDOM.render(<HomePage />, document.getElementById("root"))
```

```css
.main{
    background: #969696;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-evenly;
    align-items: center;
    flex-direction: column;
}

.createCard{
    order: 2;
    background: aqua;
    width: 100%;
    height: 120px;
}

.notificationCard{
    order: 1;
    width: 100%;
    height: 120px;
}

.clicked .notificationCard {
    order: 2;
}

.alertsCard{
    order: 4;
    width: 100%;
    background: aqua;
    height: 120px;

}

.groupsCard{
    order: 3;
    width: 100%;
    height: 120px;
}

.clicked .groupsCard {
  order: 4;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

I've added the class to the parent `<div>`, so that you can use selectors like `.clicked .notificationCard`, `.clicked .groupsCard` etc. to change the presentation of the children.

Comment: is it possible to change the order of all child elements of flex-box?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by that, but you can do what you want based on the state of your component. Maybe what you want to do is add an extra CSS class to the parent, and then use selectors like `.clicked .notificationCard` `.clicked .alertsCard` etc. to change the order property. If you have a more complex requirement, perhaps you should consider asking a new question.

Comment: What I mean is, on click of the button I need to change the order of 2 child elements.

.alertCard{
order:4
}
.notificationCard{
order:2
}

Comment: I updated the answer to change two of the children, as I hinted in my previous comment.

Answer (score -1):

Tried by accessing the style of the element, Worked!

Here is the code of the same

```js
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import style from './HomePage.css'
import * as ReactDOM from "react-dom";

class HomePage extends Component {

    onNotificationClick=()=> {
        console.log(document.getElementsByClassName(style.notificationCard));
        document.getElementsByClassName(style.notificationCard)[0].style.order = 2;
        document.getElementsByClassName(style.createCard)[0].style.order = 1;
    };

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <div className={style.main}>
                    <div className={style.createCard}>
                        Create memory
                    </div>
                    <div className={style.notificationCard}>
                        Notification
                    </div>
                    <div className={style.alertsCard}>
                        alerts
                    </div>
                    <div className={style.groupsCard}>
                        groups
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <button onClick={this.onNotificationClick}>Notification received</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default HomePage;
```

Comment: You are doing the opposite thing to what react is designed to do.